# cant position search bar on right side of header image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, searchbar

I am trying to position a search bar on the right side of an image.  The search bar defaults to the left side of the image, and I would like it to be on the right side.

I would think that

```js
searchBar.style.right = "200px";
```

should work, but it does not.

Here is the full code for the image and the search bar:

```js
function loadHeader() {
 /* Header bar */
 var headerImage = new Image(); 
 headerImage.id = "hi";
 headerImage.src = "headerBar.jpg";
 headerImage.style.position = "absolute"; 
 headerImage.style.top = "0px";
 headerImage.style.left = "0px";
 headerImage.style.zIndex = -1;
 headerImageWidth = (window.innerWidth);
 headerImage.width = headerImageWidth;
 headerImageHeight = 40;
 headerImage.height = headerImageHeight;
 document.body.appendChild(headerImage);
 
 /* Search bar */
 var searchForm = document.createElement("form");
 searchForm.setAttribute("action", "/search");
 searchForm.setAttribute("method", "POST");

 var searchBar = document.createElement("input");
 searchBar.id = "sb";
 searchBar.setAttribute("type", "text");
 searchBar.setAttribute("placeholder", "Search");
 searchBar.position = "absolute";
 searchBar.left = "500px";
 searchBar.style.zIndex = 0;
 searchBar.width = 150;
 searchBar.height = 20; 

 searchForm.appendChild(searchBar);

 document.body.appendChild(searchForm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `right` property must be used in conjunction with `position:absolute`, `position:fixed` or `position:relative`.

With `absolute`: Element will be position relative to the first *positioned* ancestor.

With `fixed`: Element will be position relative to the viewport.

With `relative`: Element will be position relative to it's normal position in the flow.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: so from what I read then, i should use `searchBar.position = "relative"` and `searchBar.style.right = "200px"` which still gets the same result.

Comment: `searchBar.**style**.position`

Comment: ok so that works if i do `searchBar.style.left = "500px"` for example...  it puts it roughly in the middle of the page.  but if i do `searchBar.style.right = "200px"` the search bar disappears completely